# Spring mvc 4 ResourceHandlers not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat8

I can not using ResourceHandler in my web app. Here is my ResourcesHandler impliment

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/img/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/script/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/script/");
}
```

My project structure :

[image: project]

My app in tomcat8 webapp foler :

[image]

I try this code to using javascript but it doesn't work :

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/script/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I try to remove "classpath:" in addResourceHandlers, no luck.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! I forgot @EnableWebMvc annotation in my configuration class, many article about static resources in spring mvc doesn't mention this problem. I hope my problem will save other a little time if they meet this one.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
{
  registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("../resources/css/");
  registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("../resources/img/");
  registry.addResourceHandler("/script/**").addResourceLocations("../resources/script/");
}
```

Comment: That seems like a really bad idea. Bad in that sentence means something like -- will not, can not, and should not, work.